# Tail call seems disabled by an enclosing try block in Akka.FSharp - but not using MaillboxProcessor

Tags: f#, tail-recursion, akka.net

Consider the following two skeletal snippets, A and B. In both cases, return! is the last executed operation and, IMHO, should be optimised like a tail call

Scenario A - here return! is properly optimised and the runtime stack is kept constant

```
let loop ... =
    actor {
        ...
        return! loop ...
    }
```

Scenario B - here return! is not interpreted as a tail call anymore and the runtime stack keeps growing, possibly leading to stack overflow exceptions

```
let loop ... =
    actor {
        try
            ...
            return! loop ...
        with ...
    }
```

The only difference is the try block which encloses the actor implementation. Note that the corresponding MailboxProcessor scenarios are both optimised as tail calls

*Full sample:*

```
open System.Threading.Tasks

// tail call in recursive function
let f n =
    let rec loop m =
        if m = 0 then printfn "f %d: false" n
        elif m = 1 then printfn "f %d: true" n
        else loop (m-2)
    loop n

// tail call in a recursive actor implementation (MailboxProcessor)
let g n =
    let c = TaskCompletionSource<bool> ()
    let a = MailboxProcessor<int>.Start <| fun (inbox:MailboxProcessor<int>) ->
        let rec loop m =
            async {
                if m = 0 then 
                    printfn "g %d: false" n
                    c.SetResult (true)
                elif m = 1 then 
                    printfn "g %d: true" n
                    c.SetResult (true)
                else 
                    return! loop (m-2)
            }
        loop n
    c.Task.Wait ()

// tail call in a recursive actor implementation enclosed in a try block (MailboxProcessor)
let g' n =
    let c = TaskCompletionSource<bool> ()
    let a = MailboxProcessor<int>.Start <| fun (inbox:MailboxProcessor<int>) ->
        let rec loop m =
            async {
                try
                    if m = 0 then 
                        printfn "g' %d: false" n
                        c.SetResult (true)
                    elif m = 1 then 
                        printfn "g' %d: true" n
                        c.SetResult (true)
                    else 
                        return! loop (m-2)
                with | ex -> printfn "*** %s" ex.Message
            }
        loop n
    c.Task.Wait ()

open Akka.Actor
open Akka.Configuration
open Akka.FSharp

let akka_config = ConfigurationFactory.ParseString <|  @"
    akka {
        suppress-json-serializer-warning = on
    }
    "

let akka_system = ActorSystem.Create ("Akka", akka_config)

let get = 
    let mutable x = 0
    fun () ->
        x <- x + 1
        x

// tail call in a recursive actor implementation (Akka.FSharp)        
let h n =
    let c = TaskCompletionSource<bool> ()
    let a = spawn akka_system (sprintf "actor_%d" (get ())) <| fun (inbox:Actor<int>) ->
        let rec loop m =
            actor {
                if m = 0 then 
                    printfn "h %d: false" n
                    c.SetResult (true)
                elif m = 1 then 
                    printfn "h %d: true" n
                    c.SetResult (true)
                else 
                    return! loop (m-2)
            }
        loop n
    c.Task.Wait ()

// tail call in a recursive actor implementation enclosed in a try block (Akka.FSharp)
let h' n =
    let c = TaskCompletionSource<bool> ()
    let a = spawn akka_system (sprintf "actor_%d" (get ())) <| fun (inbox:Actor<int>) ->
        let rec loop m =
            actor {
                try
                    if m = 0 then 
                        printfn "h' %d: false" n
                        c.SetResult (true)
                    elif m = 1 then 
                        printfn "h' %d: true" n
                        c.SetResult (true)
                    else 
                        return! loop (m-2)
                with | ex -> printfn "*** %s" ex.Message
            }
        loop n
    c.Task.Wait ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    for n in [0; 1; 1000; 1001; 1000000; 1000001;] do
        f n
        g n
        g' n
        h n
        h' n
        printfn ""
    0
```

I get StackOverflowException for (h' 1000000) - i.e. for Akka.FSharp with the extra try block

Comment: It's great that you've found it! Since this is clearly a bug report with repro steps, an issue on official github repository would probably be more on place than putting it as a question on Stack Overflow, but thanks anyway ;)

Comment: Dziękuję Ci, Horusiath! I will post this issue on the github repository.